# TFS query for tasks with no parent

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I would like create a Flat list of work items query in TFS in which the results contain all of the specified PBI and Bug cases and any Task cases that have no parent.

It's that Task with no parent part that has me perplexed.  I cannot see a way that I can do what seems so obvious such as (Parent Link Count = 0) because that attribute is not exposed to me though, strangely, some other link type counts are.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You need to change the type of your query to the Direct Links query, then choose the option to pull back all work items without any matching links.  The results will still be a flat list.

[image]

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you.  I had tried that but was trying to include a filter for Task types on the filters for linked work items rather than just putting it with the rest of them on top level work items.

Comment: It does not help if you want to create a chart. Charts do not support hierarchical queries. Flat queries do not support filtering by parent. Checkmate.