# TFS Query - Parent with missing child link

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I thought I'd have better luck based on [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681059/tfs-query-for-tasks-with-no-parent) posting I had found, but unfortunately I'm not getting the results I need.

I need to pull parent task / stories where we have missing child links.  Just for context, all of our parent "stories" have underlying child "tasks" to ensure we follow proper "definition of done" lifecycle.  I need to find stories where any tasks (filtering by keyword) would be missing.   Any way to do this?

[image: TFS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find something without link you have to set the filter options: "Only return items that do not have matching links". Your example [TFS query for tasks with no parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681059/tfs-query-for-tasks-with-no-parent) contains that.

Try this template with the filter grouping:
[image]

Comment: This works partially, but somehow the resulting stories don't appear to have any links at all, not just the ones from my filter, so I might have to debug this option to get a better understanding of how it actually works.

Comment: In your case you need to adjust your query to find all user stories with tasks ("peer reviews" and "Acceptance") and option "Only return items that have matching links". Then switch the filter option to "Only return items that do not have matching links". I`ve updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you sir!  I believe that returns what I'm looking for...  doing some spot checks now, looks good!  Cheers!