# How to query stories without parent feature link?

Tags: tfs

In a given area path, I would to get the list of stories that does not have parent feature link.  How should I write the query for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS query for tasks with no parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681059/tfs-query-for-tasks-with-no-parent)

Comment: Hi Kay, hope you are doing well. How about this issue? **Only return items that do not have matching links" should work as your demand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve you could change the type of your query to the **Work items and Direct Links** query, then choose the option to pull back all work items without any matching links.  The results will still be a flat list.

In the filters for top level work items, just add a filed to specify a detail area path and choose corresponding work item type.

[image]

More details please take a look at our official here: [Use direct links to view dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies)

Hope this helps.